# Would asking for examples/counterexamples in probability be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I think it would be of interest to some to post examples and/or counterexamples in Probability. Those could be posed as: "is there an example of an object with properties A, B, C,..  that doesn't have property Z". However, a post like this could be more mathematical and of narrow interest than the typical post here. And maybe it could find a home on math overflow (where one can also post equations). Any suggestions/ recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think basic probability examples belong to math.stackexchange.com whereas basic statistics examples belong on this site.

Comment: I disagree.  Exact tests (for example) are essentially exercises in probability and do not rely on parameter estimates or statistics per se.  Basic issues of probability are fundamental to statistics in that statistics is (often) an attempt to mathematically estimate the probability of an event. Thus, issues of probability especially if _applied_ in a data analytic context should be welcome here.

Answer (score 6):

I think that, so long as it relates to data analysis in some way, it's relevant.  Regardless of whether it's probability, set theory, or a cutting-edge technique that few people would have heard of...

Regarding equations: I believe that latex support is going to be implemented here.  So that shouldn't be a reason by itself.